# Using vectorization to get a specific matrix output from two vectors

Tags: matlab

I wanted to know if there is a efficient way using MATLAB vectorization to generate a specific matrix from two vectors.

Suppose the vectors are

```
x = [u v]

y = [a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3]
```

where u, v, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3 are some real numbers.

The 2-column matrix that I wish to generate using these vectors is

```
M = [u  a1;
     u  a2;
     u  a3;
     v  a1;
     v  a2;
     v  a3;
     u  b1;
     u  b2;
     u  b3;
     v  b1;
     v  b2;
     v  b3]
```

In general, the length of x can be anything and the length of y is multiple of 3. Here is the code that I have now, but I think there should some better way (that possibly avoids the use of for-loop):

```
M = [];
Y = reshape(y, 3, []);

for j = 1:size(Y, 2)
    [a, b] = meshgrid(x, Y(:, j));
    L = [a(:) b(:)];
    M = [M; L];
end
```

Comment: This is very vague. What are the actual requirements for your matrix? How general are you trying to make this? Have you done *anything* to solve this yourself?

Comment: I have edited the problem description to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `repmat` and `repelem` :

```
M = [repmat(repelem(x(:),3),numel(y)/3,1) , ...
reshape(repmat(reshape(y,3,[]),numel(x),1),[],1)];
```

Comment: Here's an IDEOne link to the equivalent Octave code: https://ideone.com/n5U33o. It has a small tweak to get around the missing `repelem` function.

Comment: [repelems](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/repelems.html) also may be useful.

Comment: Sure, except that IDEOne's octave does not support it yet.

Answer (score 0):

you have a pretty strange order in M. Is that order important? if not, or if you are happy to fix the order later yourself I have two solutions:

1) code

```
[a,b] = meshgrid(x,y);
M = [a(:) b(:)]
```

will give you:

```
M = [
 u  a1
 u  a2
 u  a3
 u  b1
 u  b2
 u  b3
 v  a1
 v  a2
 v  a3
 v  b1
 v  b2
 v  b3]
```

and

2) code `M = combvec(x, y)'` gives you:

```
M = [
 u  a1
 v  a1
 u  a2
 v  a2
 u  a3
 v  a3
 u  b1
 v  b1
 u  b2
 v  b2
 u  b3
 v  b3]
```

Comment: So how do you get the final answer? Why would you assume the order in the question is wrong?

Comment: But then you proceed to generate two matrices that don't match what OP wants and imply that one of them should do fine.

Comment: neither of your solutions provides the correct first column.